# Batchfile script to find out installed GPU

Tags: batch-file, gpu, wmic

I am busy making some scripts for automatic installation using AIK. Everything is going well, except on one point, to find out which GPU is installed. The idea is that the Drivers installation starts automaticly. Problem is when I add the drivers directly to the driverstore I get some problems whit the cards.

We have next to the in CPU integrated GPU also the Nvidia N210, GT610 and now on the new machines the GT710. And that causes some problems. Now I want to make a script containing a query about the installed GPU and run the appropriated driver.

First wmic came to my mind. But `wmic path win32_VideoController get name` will display the installed driver, in this case "Default-VGA-Adapter".

So what could I do? Is there a wax to use de VEN&DEV information somehow?

Comment: Does Caption show the same as name? `wmic path Win32_VideoController get Name, Caption, Availability`

Comment: Yes it does. But i am a little further now. "wmic path win32_pnpentity get PNPDeviceID" will list all devices on the computer.

Comment: So are you able to identify the gpu by that?

Comment: Sure you'd be able to make something from `wmic PATH Win32_VideoController get Name, PNPDeviceID, Adapterram`

Comment: Ah yes... wmic Path Win32_VideoController get PNPDeviceID did it.... I'll try to make something whit that. Thanks.

Comment: So suppose your question is no longer needed then? :)

Comment: It is working. Thanks again. Is there a Resolved or Close button somewhere?

Comment: Well, I did not technically give an answer, so if I did and you mark it, it is unfair. So you could just delete the question?